# x86: using memory / swapping values?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm just getting into x86 for a systems class and have a couple of questions:

1) Say I reference a piece of memory with:

```
(%eax)
```

The parentheses indicate I'm accessing memory and `%eax` indicates I want to access *that* particular address in memory.  So if register `%eax` stores `0x104`, `(%eax)` will return whatever is stored at memory location 0x104.  Is this correct?

2) Say I want to swap the values stored at `(%eax)` and `(%ebx)`.  Here's my 
attempt:

```
//store values in registers
movl (%eax) eax
movl (%ebx) ebx

//store values in opposite registers from where they came originally
movl ebx (%eax)
movl eax (%ebx)
```

Does this look right?

Thanks for the help,
bclayman

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) No. (Even ignoring the missing commas.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That cannot be correct.

`EAX` and `EBX` start out containing memory locations.  You then dereference the memory, moving the actual values into the registers of the same name:

```
 MOVL (%EAX), EAX
 MOVL (%EBX), EBX
```

`EAX` and `EBX` no longer contain memory addresses; they now contain the contents from those addresses.  When you next do this:

```
 MOVL EBX, (%EAX)
 MOVL EAX, (%EBX)
```

you are storing  the values from those memory locations into whatever memory location happens to be equal to those values which is almost certainly not what you want and almost guaranteed not to exchange the values.

The only way this *would* work if the memory locations were storing the value of the memory location in themselves, which wouldn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on the second part.  The first two statements seem to be what I want to do (storing the values from memory into registers).  Specifically, I'm not sure what you mean here: "you are storing the values from those memory locations into whatever memory location happens to be equal to those values"...Thanks!

Comment: @bclayman: Maybe it could be worded better. The key thing to understand here is that %EAX and EAX is the same register. So for example if the original value of %EAX was 0x104 and the data in RAM at address 0x104 was 0x333, doing `movl EAX, (%EAX)` stores the value 0x333 at RAM address 0x333

Comment: @slebetman Hmm, so if EAX == 0x104, (%EAX) is M[0x104] == 0x333, then why would movl EAX, (%EAX) not move the value 0x104 into RAM address 0x104?  Thanks again!

Comment: Because %EAX is no longer 0x104 since you copied its value to itself: `movl (%EAX), EAX`. Maybe I should have said that.. :)

Answer (score 3):

1) Yes, if you a reading a value.  If you are writing a value, it doesn't matter what is in location 0x104, it is going to overwritten.

2) No. Your code starts by destroying the values in the targeted memory locations,
   by storing the address of the memory location *in* the memory location.

[There is some confusion on my part reading your assembly notation: in many assemblers,  one writes just "eax", not "%eax"; these aren't different registers.    I don't know if you are writing that because your assembler requires you to do that [[which assembler are you using?]] or if that is just a typo.  In what follow, I always use the bare register name, in 
MASM assembly syntax]

To swap two locations, you pretty much need the original two and
someplace to temporarily store the original values:

```
  mov   ecx, [eax]    ; fetch memory specified by address in eax
  mov   edx, [ebx]    ; fetch memory specified by address in ebx
  mov   [eax], edx    ; put 2nd value where 1st used to be
  mov   [ebx], ecx    ; put 1st value where 2nd used to be
```

If you are "swapping" registers (e.g, eax and ebx), you can get with just one temporary:

```
  mov   ecx, eax      ; save 1st value in temp location ecx
  mov   eax, ebx      ; set 1st value to 2nd location
  mov   ebx, ecx      ; set 2nd value to copy of 1st value
```

The x86 has a special "xchg" instruction which makes this easy:

```
  xchg  eax, ebx      ; exchange  eax with ebx
```

You can arguably use this on memory location:

```
  mov   ecx, [eax]    ; save 1st value in temporary ecx
  xchg  ecx, [ebx]    ; swap with 2nd value
  mov   [eax], ecx    ; set 2nd value to swapped temp
```

Unfortunately, xchg used with a memory location includes a free implicit LOCK, used for multiprocessor synchronization, and that makes this code
a lot slower than the first solution above.

Comment: I think the original poster is using AT&T syntax which prefixes register names with % and reverses the order the operands.

Comment: Aha.  Well, that's the trouble with assemblers; everybody invents their own syntax.  The  "%" being optional is pretty confusing, IMHO.  I think my answer still stands, if OP understands my syntax is different than his and the operand order is reversed :-}

Comment: The % isn't optional in AT&T syntax, but then neither are the commas. AT&T syntax also uses `(%eax)` and MOVL where MASM uses `[eax]` and MOV DWORD PTR. (MASM interprets `mov eax,(eax)` as being `mov eax,eax`.)

Comment: @RossRidge: Sigh, you're right.  I've seen *so* many syntaxes that I sometimes kind of lose track.  To my surprise, my late night brain had no trouble reading OP's (...) as "indexed by", now I understand why AT&T syntax needs the % on the indirected register.    And contaminated by that, I wrote (...) in my answer for [...].   Edited.   Syntax checkers are good.

Comment: Is the mnemonic shortened from `xchg` to `xch`?

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen   Not on purpose.  Fixed.

Comment: @Ajay Brahmakshatriya: thanks for noticing bug in the last example.  While your edit got rejected because of additional text, I think you bug fix was right and have made that change.